# C - Not able to run a C program in any IDE (Tried with Netbeans and VSCode)

Tags: c, netbeans, mingw

I installed MinGW compiler to run a C/C++ program. When I check the compiler version it shows this:

[image: gccVersion]

This is my MinGW directory:

[image: MinGWpath]

This is my **PATH** setting:

[image: PATHsetting]

I have set my **PATH** environment variable as follows: 
`%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\bin;`

Whenever I run my C/C++ project in Netbeans, it's giving me below error even though my program build is getting successful:

[image: error]

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: @P__J__ Of course it is a programming question! The OP is try to run a C program in NetBeans. There are literally thousands of questions like this on SO. Note that _"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**."_ The question is on topic.

Comment: @skomisa it is not. he has missconfigured computer. that's the main issue

Comment: If you know what he has done incorrectly then post your solution.

Comment: Please update your question with a screen shot of your C/C++ settings in  NetBeans: **Tools > Options > C/C++** then click the **Build Tools** tab.

Comment: Long shot (and probably unsecure) but try running Netbeans `As an Administrator`. It appears you have insufficient permissions.

Comment: @John If the OP is able to call GCC from the non-administrator `cmd`, why should the IDE need administrator rights?

Comment: @thebusybee It appears the IDE can't start the compiled program. So even if the OP/IDE can compile it, the IDE fails to run it for some reason. Running it as an admin could prove this is correct. Then the OP can investigate further why the IDE can't run the program without admin privileges.

Comment: @John Oh, you are perfectly right. The tiny screenshot proves again that text should be inserted in the question as text, not as image. :-} -- If your suspicion is right, why does GCC, which was run as standard user, produce an executable that can't be run as standard user?

Comment: @thebusybee I highly suspect it's the Windows Defender / antivirus. Have a look at https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/7ajukb/permission_denied_code_doesnt_run_or_debug/